# pandas-like rolling on a Datetime column in DolphinDB

Tags: python, pandas, window, dolphindb

pandas DataFrame provides rolling window calculations on a DatetimeIndex or a Datetime-typed column like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4]},
...                   index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
...                            pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:02'),
...                            pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:03'),
...                            pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:05'),
...                            pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:06')])
```

```
>>> df.rolling('3s').sum()
                       B
2013-01-01 09:00:00  0.0
2013-01-01 09:00:02  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:03  3.0
2013-01-01 09:00:05  2.0
2013-01-01 09:00:06  4.0
```

DolphinDB's `moving` function, as well as functions of the moving-family like `msum`, `mavg`, etc., is calculated based on a window with a fixed number of elements inside. But they are unable to handle temporal types.

```
df = table(0 1 2 NULL 4 as B,
           [2013.01.01 09:00:00,2013.01.01 09:00:02,2013.01.01 09:00:03,2013.01.01 09:00:05,2013.01.01 09:00:06] as index)
select index, msum(B, 3) as B from df
```

```
index               B
------------------- -
2013.01.01T09:00:00  
2013.01.01T09:00:02  
2013.01.01T09:00:03 3
2013.01.01T09:00:05 3
2013.01.01T09:00:06 6
```

I'd like to do a rolling calculation with the window being a time period that could include variable-sized elements.

Answer (score 0):

DolphinDB Orca API has the same function, in your case:

```
odf = orca.DataFrame(df)
odf.rolling('3s').sum()
```